# Availability message

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I change the product availability message based upon the day that the customer is viewing (or ordering) the product?

Day of order :                            Will ship in X # of days

Sunday      :                               2

Monday         :                            1

Tuesday (before 10am)         :             0

Tuesday (after 10am)          :             2

Wednesday                      :            1

Thursday (before 10am)          :           0

Thursday (after 10am)              :        5

Friday                         :            4

Saturday                             :      3

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a new module with a helper that uses http://php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

You have your logic listed above maybe write a switch statement that outputs your delivery message and the number of days is determined from the output if the switch statement.

Then its just a case of calling this helper function in your themes availability template file to output your delivery message.